# How do I resize TextBox to fit the Window size when it Maximized/Minimized?

Tags: c#, wpf

How can I resize my TextBoxe's/Label's to fit the window size when I maximize/minimize it? At this point textboxes just go to the center of the window. What I want that they resized to fit the grid columns and rows size. How can I do that? I tried to difine to what column and row textbox belongs, thougth, it will resize accordingly to ColumnDefinition, but that didn't change anything.

```
<DockPanel Margin="2,46,0,0" Name="dockPanel1" Width="Auto">
        <TabControl Height="Auto" Name="tabControl1" Width="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <TabItem Header="tabItem1" Name="tabItem1">
                <Grid Name="grid1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="523" Width="766">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition MinHeight="0" Height="43*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="45*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="435*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="0" Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" MinWidth="100" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="385*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <TextBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Height="27" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,4,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="141" FontSize="14" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" />
                    <Label Content="Label" Height="9" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="16,7,0,0" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="35" />
                    <Label Content="Supplier" Height="27" Name="label2" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="14" FontFamily="Tahoma" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="6,4,0,0" Width="133" IsEnabled="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Foreground="Black" Background="White" />
                    <TextBox FontSize="14" Height="27" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="140,6,0,0" Name="textBox11" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="141" Grid.Row="1" />
                    <Label Content="Supplier Bank" FontFamily="Tahoma" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" Height="27" Margin="6,6,142,0" Name="label3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="133" Grid.Row="1" Background="White" />
                    <TextBox FontSize="14" Height="27" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="140,7,0,0" Name="textBox12" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="141" Grid.Row="2" />
                    <Label Content="Account Number" FontFamily="Tahoma" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" Height="27" Margin="6,7,142,0" Name="label4" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="133" Grid.Row="2" Background="White" />
                    <TextBox FontSize="14" Height="27" Margin="134,4,110,0" Name="textBox2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="141" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=grid1, Path=ActualWidth}" />
                    <Label Content="Buyer" FontFamily="Tahoma" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" Height="27" Margin="0,4,252,0" Name="label5" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="133" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" Background="White" />
                    <TextBox FontSize="14" Grid.Row="1" Height="27" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="134,6,0,0" Name="textBox3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="141" Grid.Column="2" />
                    <Label Content="Buyer Bank" FontFamily="Tahoma" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Row="1" Height="27" Margin="0,6,0,0" Name="label6" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="133" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="White" />
                    <TextBox FontSize="14" Grid.Row="2" Height="27" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="134,7,0,0" Name="textBox4" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="141" Grid.Column="2" />
                    <Label Content="Account Number" FontFamily="Tahoma" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Row="2" Height="27" Margin="0,7,0,0" Name="label7" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="133" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="White" />
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
            <TabControl.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0.035" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF1B327A" Offset="0.528" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF001E98" Offset="0.278" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </TabControl.Background>
        </TabControl>
    </DockPanel>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dont use a static value for the width attribute.

You can try "HorizontalAlignment=Stretch".

Comment: Thank you. Now I understood my mistake.